# How to get the booking ID where current page ID in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress-theming, wordpress

What php code can be used to retrieve the current page ID in a Wordpress theme? Then pull the booking_type_id from the database that is linked to that ID.

I have tried so many different things and I just cant seem to get it to work.
I am trying to use something along the lines of

```
<?php
   $bookingid = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT booking_type_id FROM hobookingtypes WHERE post_id = 'the_ID();' ");

   // Echo the booking resource id
   echo $bookingid;
?>
```

But I am really not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Try like this: `$bookingid = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT booking_type_id FROM hobookingtypes WHERE post_id = "+the_ID()+");`

Comment: `the_ID()` function need to be used in while loop. and `the_ID()` echos the ID. So you can not use `the_ID()` function in query.

Comment: Hi @AzizShaikh what dose the + around the the_ID() do? I haven't seen this before

Comment: That's because it's a mistake, attempting to concat with a JavaScript style string join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `the_ID()` because its echo the POST_ID, so use the global object `$post` the provide all the information related to post;

```
global $post;

$bookingid = $wpdb->get_var(
    "SELECT booking_type_id FROM hobookingtypes 
       WHERE 
          post_id = '". $post->ID ."'"
);

// Echo the booking resource id
echo $bookingid;
```

#### Alternative of global $post:

OR you can use `get_the_ID()` instead of `the_ID()`

Comment: Awesome you guys where all so quick.

@jogesh_pi your solution worked perfectly for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get current post ID with this code,

```
global $post;
$id = $post->ID;
```

or just,

```
global $post_id;
$id = $post_id;
```

or you can use,

`get_the_ID()` function insted.